# mapDispatchToProps: any point?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I was wondering if there was still a point using `mapDispatchToProps` today.
I'm working on the [redux documentation tutorials](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) (to build a todo list) where `VisibleTodoList` is described as:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleTodo } from '../actions'
import TodoList from '../components/TodoList'

const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case 'SHOW_ALL':
      return todos
    case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
      return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
      return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)

export default VisibleTodoList
```

However, I've been told that today, I could simply not to define `mapDispatchToProps` and connect everything through:

```
const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  toggleTodo
)(TodoList)
```

Is it right? And if so, what is the point to write a `mapDispatchToProps`? Is there any drawbacks to simply returning the action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To clarify the other Mark's comment:

The second argument to `connect()` can take two main forms.  If you pass a function as the argument, `connect()` assumes you want to handle dispatch preparation yourself, calls your function with `dispatch` as an argument, and merges the result into the props for your component.

If you pass in an object as the second argument to `connect()`, it assumes you've given it a map of prop names to action creators, and so it automatically runs all of them through the `bindActionCreators` utility and uses the result as props.

However, passing a *single* action creator as the second argument, as your example appears to do, would not do what you want, as `connect()` would interpret that as a preparation function and not an action creator that needs to be bound.

So yes, `connect()` supports a shorthand syntax of passing in an object full of action creators as the second argument, but there are still good use cases for passing in an actual `mapDispatchToProps` function to do things yourself (especially if your dispatch prep relies on the actual prop values in some way).

You might want to refer to [the API docs for `connect()](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

Comment: Ah... why do you say `mapDispatch` takes _three_ args? Per the source, it's only ever called with either one or two.

Comment: Just want to add that the last line, especially if your dispatch prep relies on the actual prop values in some way is exactly why I still prep some of my action creators myself. In fact its rarely stated that mapDispatchToProps actually takes 2 arguments, the 2nd of which is ownProps and its here I can inject default arguments into my action creators from the container object props and not have to pass them down to children components. (Thanks for the reminder markerikson, I couldn't edit the comment again so I just reposted it with the correction).

Answer (score 8):

connect() will automatically bind dispatch to your actions if they are passed in as an object of function names.

So no, you don't need to implement mapStateToProps. Instead you can just pass you actions like this:

```
export default connect((state) => state, {
  action1,
  action2,
})(MyComponent);
```