# Redux store doesn't change with the change of react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to change the redux store based on the current state change, state changes correctly but the `this.props` still as the initialization. here's my code:

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetchMatches();
  }

  handleChange(newDateRange){
    console.log('====================================');
    console.log('handleChange fired');
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log('====================================');
  }


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    handleChange: (newDateRange) =>
      dispatch({
      ...this.props.home,
      startDate: newDateRange[0],
      endDate: newDateRange[1]
    })
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { mapDispatchToProps, fetchMatches })(Home);
```

and here's the implementation for `DateRange`:

```
<DateRangeInput className="daterange" value={[this.props.startDate, this.props.endDate]} onChange={this.handleChange}  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
  return {
    handleChange: (newDateRange) =>
      dispatch({
      ...ownProps.home,
      startDate: newDateRange[0],
      endDate: newDateRange[1]
    })
  }
}
```

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/issues/250

Comment: This doesn't run when i change the value of the `DateRange`, How can i make this fired on `handleChange` function called?

Comment: `this.props.handleChange([startDate, endDate])`

Comment: `<DateRangeInput value={[this.props.startDate, this.props.endDate]}  onChange={this.props.handleChange} />`
How can i do this here?

Comment: I dont know how to `DateRangeInput` works, can you log the result with `handleChange` handleChange: (v) => console.log(v)

Comment: Doesn't called! doesn't log anything!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access props inside mapDispatchToProps from this as the function is invoked even before the component is mounted. Instead access it from mapDispatchToProps which exposes the previous props in the second parameter.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
  return {
    handleChange: (newDateRange) =>
      dispatch({
      ...ownProps.home,
      startDate: newDateRange[0],
      endDate: newDateRange[1]
    })
  }
}
```

[mapDispatchToProps API Documentation](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

Comment: This doesn't run when i change the value of the `DateRange`, How can i make this fired on `handleChange` function called?

Comment: Can you share the DateRange implementation. Also may I ask why the second parameter in connect is an object instead of just : 
`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);`

Comment: If you pass in an object as the second argument to connect(), it assumes you've given it a map of prop names to action creators, and so it automatically runs all of them through the bindActionCreators utility and uses the result as props.

Currently with `{ mapDispatchToProps, fetchMatches }` as second parameter, react-redux assumes that both `mapDispatchToProps` and `fetchMatches` are action creators.
Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325419/mapdispatchtoprops-any-point)